# Is there a way to block changes to an area using command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am looking for a way to make it so no one can edit a small area of space I select. Is there a way to do this?

I'd prefer not to use any mods, I'm looking for a solution using command blocks. Is this possible?

I am using a Singleplayer world, not a server

Comment: Pretty sure there is no such command in vanilla.

Comment: Disclaimer: I haven't actually tested this. Command block: `/testfor @p[r=5,name=!USERNAMEHERE]`. Hook it up to a 5-torch, add a comparator. Hook the comparator up to a command block that teleports them away.

Comment: Hey @user77479, did Gigazelle's answer help you? If so, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark under the vote count. This shows future visitors what worked for you, and awards Gigazelle (and yourself!) some extra rep :-)

Comment: I meant to like protect a spawn point so teleporting them away won't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hook this up to a clock, repeating every few seconds:

**`/effect @p[r=10] 4 10 5 true`**

This gives any player in the radius of 10 blocks level 5 mining fatigue (Potion effect 4) for 10 seconds. Whenever they're in the area, they cannot break any blocks. When they leave, the potion effect wears off so they can break blocks again.

Comment: Also, if you don't want it to apply to you, you can modify the `[r=10]` bit to say `[r=10,name=!<yourUsername>]` (No, that's not a typo, that's actually how Minecraft's syntax works).